# What is mutating in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to code a function which will find the max distance between a given point and a list of other points, in Scheme. One of the requirements is that I must not use mutation. So what is mutation in Scheme? After googling around a bit, I think set and define is mutation but nothing specific about let.

WHopefully some of you can clarify this for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutation means changing the value of a thing that already exists, and the names of mutating procedures in Scheme usually have a "!" at the end.

`define` and `let` create new things, so they can't mutate anything.

`set!`, on the other hand, assigns a new value to something.

Comment: In your explanation, wouldn't 'object' be a better substitute for 'thing'?

Comment: I chose "thing" because it's more general; "object" tends to make people think of object-oriented programming or Java or other languages they know about where "object" has a specific meaning. No language that I'm aware of uses "thing", so everyone knows what it is.

Comment: Hmm, if someone was to look for Java objects in a Scheme implementation, well, you should probably let them do it for greater good, eh? :O